# How to Update Blender

Tags: system

I want to update to 2.8, and it looks like I just have to download that version. Will i have to delete my old version or will it automatically replace it?

Comment: That's why it's best to use ZIPs. To update you just delete the previous version folder and unzip the latest one.

Comment: what OS are you on? in some it might update automatically

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 here, and I use a desktop shortcut; You can download it, unzip to inside your "Blender Foundation" folder in Program Files, it shouldn't delete the other versions.  You will have to make a new shortcut on the desktop for the new version.  Then you can delete the Zip file, or keep it.